# How to set a custom sorting order for a Documents module subpanel in SuiteCRM 7.9.1

Tags: javascript, php, sorting, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I trying to sort by active_date using the file layoutdefs.php

```
  $layout_defs['Documents']['subpanel_setup']['documents'] = array(
        'order' => 50,
        'sort_order' => 'desc',
        'sort_by' => 'active_date',
   );
```

I make a quick repair and rebuild but the sorting not works, then this show me the module with shuffled records..

how can i do a custom sort?

Comment: you are using correct syntax. Make sure that you didn't applied custom sorting by clicking field label in sub-panel. If you choose to sort on any other fields from front end then your defined one inside definition will be overridden.